# How to run my android project on two AVD's at the same time

Tags: android, eclipse, tcp, android-activity, android-virtual-device

In eclipse I have an android activity that can send tcp packets (over a virtual TCP stack). I need to start two instances of that activity so that I can test whether messages sent by one activity will be received by the other actvity.

How can I do this? I can only run the android project once which fires up the main activity, but I have not been able to find how to fire up two vritual devices running the same project simultaneously.

Hope you can help me out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two Android Virtual devices, and run one instance of the application in each. Maybe when you launched the app the first time you checked the "use this device for future launches" and hence they chooser is not showing to let you pick which AVD you want to use. There should be no problem running two AVDs at the same time.